# I have confusion in this block of code where div function is used in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

.model small
.stack 100h
.data

e db "Even Number$"
o db "Odd Number$"

.code

```
Start:

Mov ax,@data
Mov ds,ax

Mov ah,01
int 21h

Mov bl,2
div bl

cmp ah,0
je eve

Mov ah,02
Mov dl,0AH
int 21h

Mov dx,offset o
Mov ah,09
int 21h

Mov ah,4ch
int 21h

eve:
    
Mov ah,02
Mov dl,0AH
int 21h


Mov dx,offset e
Mov ah,09
int 21h

Mov ah,4ch
int 21h 

end start
```

I am confused about this block of code
Mov bl,2
div bl
I use this div as a modulo
The confusion is how this is used as modulo
because in divide if we do 2/2 so answer will be 1
so how the output is appeared as even number

Comment: The result in AH is the remainder, not the quotient.  This is an inefficient way to test for odd with `test al, 1` or `and al, 1` / `jz even` to check the low bit.

Comment: can you please tell me which one is efficient way to test even odd??

Comment: Oops, sorry for the unclear phrasing.  `test al, 1` / `jz even` *is* efficient.  So is `and al, 1` if you want a 0 or 1 in a register, instead of just a FLAGS result.  TEST is just AND that only writes FLAGS, not the first operand, so they're both fast.  `div` is slowest integer instruction, by a large margin.  See https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/